# How to connect Microsoft SQL Server with Dart

Tags: sql-server, dart

Can anyone tell me how to connect to a SQL Server database with Dart? I've been reading and searching for days but can't find any suitable answers.

today i've been testing this:
https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket
it works but now I get an error in the code:

in the git file called sqlconnection I get to this function and when I return the following error occurs:

SocketSQL:
[here you can see that he really listens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw0iH.png)

ERROR:

```
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String>'
```

CODE:

```
   /// formats and write a command to the socket
   Future<String> _SendCommand(String command)
   {
      // prepare buffer for response
      _receiveBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      
      _completer = new Completer();
      String cmd = command.length.toString() + "\r\n" + command;
      _socket.write(cmd);

      return _completer.future; // this line return to ComprobarConnexio() and get error
   }
```

Main Code

```
void main() async{
  runApp(MyApp());
  ComprobarConnexion();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainMenu(),
      theme: new ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'San Francisco',
        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 1),
      ),
    );
  }
 }
 ComprobarConnexion() async {
   var conn = new SqlConnection("SERVER=****;Database=***;Uid=****;Password=****",address: '****', port: ****);
  print(Text('Starting connection'),);
  try {
    await conn.open();
    print(Text('Connection OPEN!'),);
  }
  catch(e){
     print(e);
     print(Text('Connection Failed'),);
  }
  await conn.close();
  print(Text('Connection Closed'),);

}
```

Comment: Though I must admit I know nothing of dart, a [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+connect+Microsoft+SQL+Server+with+Dart) of your title instantly gave what appears to be promising results. To avoid downvotes, I would suggest showing what you've already looked at in your question; you say you have been reading for "days" so you must have read a huge number of articles or documentation by now. What about those articles, or the documentation didn't you understand or why didn't they help? What were those articles and documentation?

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I hope to find the solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was a github code bug, i leave the git code here in case anyone finds the same to me ma worked, thanks for all the help.

File: sqlConnection.dart

```
library sql_server_socket;

import "dart:io";
import "dart:async";
import "dart:convert";

import "table.dart";

class SqlConnection
{
   Socket _socket;
   StringBuffer _receiveBuffer;
   Completer _completer;
   bool _connected;
   
   String _address;
   int _port;
   String _connectionString;
   
   SqlConnection(String connStr, {String address: "localhost", int port: 10980})
   {
      _address = address;
      _port = port;
      _connected = false;
      _connectionString = connStr;
   }
   
   /// tells if database is connected
   bool get connected => _connected;  
   
   /// connects to sql server database using the specified connection string
   Future<dynamic> open() async
   {
      try
      {
         this._socket = await Socket.connect(_address, _port);
         print("Connected to: ${_socket.remoteAddress.address}:${_socket.remotePort}");
      }
      catch(ex)
      {
         throw "can't connect to ${_address}:${_port} -- $ex";         
      }
       
      //Establish the onData, and onDone callbacks
      utf8.decoder.bind(_socket).listen(_receiveData, onError: _onError, onDone: _onDone);

      var connectCompleter = new Completer();
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "open", "text": _connectionString });
      
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
         var res = _parseResult(result);
         if(res is _OkResult)
         {
           _connected = true;
           connectCompleter.complete(true);
         }
         else if(res is _ErrorResult)
         {
           _connected = false;
           connectCompleter.completeError(res.error);         
         }
         else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
         _connected = false;
         connectCompleter.completeError(err);
      });         
       
      return connectCompleter.future;
   }
   
   /// disconnects from sql server
   Future<dynamic> close()
   {
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      Completer disconnectCompleter = new Completer();
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "close", "text": "" });
      
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((risp)
      {
         var res = _parseResult(risp);
         
         if(res is _OkResult) 
         {
            _connected = false;
            disconnectCompleter.complete(true);
         }
         else if(res is _ErrorResult)
         {           
            disconnectCompleter.completeError(res.error);           
         }
         else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
        disconnectCompleter.completeError(err);    
      });               
      
      return disconnectCompleter.future;     
   }
   
   /// launch a query on the database, returning a table
   Future<Table> queryTable(String SQL)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "table", "text": SQL });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);

               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);          
          else if(res is _TableResult) 
          {
              var tres = res as _TableResult;              
              Table tab = new Table(this, tres.tableName, tres.rows, tres.columns);
              compl.complete(tab);
          }
          else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;
   }

   Future<PostBackResponse> postBack(ChangeSet chg)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String params = json.encode(chg.toEncodable());
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "postback", "text": params });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);

               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);          
          else if(res is _PostBackResult) 
          {
              var tres = res as _PostBackResult; 
              PostBackResponse resp = new PostBackResponse();
              resp.idcolumn = tres.idcolumn;
              resp.identities = tres.identities;              
              compl.complete(resp);
          }
          else throw "invalid postback response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;           
   }
   
   /// launch a query on the database, returning all rows
   Future<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> query(String SQL)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "query", "text": SQL });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);
               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);         
          else if(res is _QueryResult) compl.complete(res.rows);          
          else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;
   }
   
   /// launch a query on the database, returning the first rows only
   Future<dynamic> querySingle(String SQL)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "querysingle", "text": SQL });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);
          
               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);          
          else if(res is _QueryResult)
          {   
              if(res.rows.length==0) compl.complete(null);
              else                   compl.complete(res.rows[0]);
          }
          else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;
   }

   /// launch a query on the database, returning the value from the first column of the first row
   Future<dynamic> queryValue(String SQL)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "queryvalue", "text": SQL });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);

               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);         
          else if(res is _QueryResult)
          {
              if(res.rows.length==0) compl.complete(null);
              else                   compl.complete(res.rows[0]["value"]);
          }
          else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;
   }

   /// executes a sql command, returning the number of rows affected
   Future<int> execute(String SQL)
   {      
      if(!connected) throw "not connected";
      
      String JSON = json.encode({ "type": "execute", "text": SQL });
      
      Completer compl = new Completer(); 
      _SendCommand(JSON).then((result)
      {
          var res = _parseResult(result);
          
               if(res is _ErrorResult) compl.completeError(res.error);          
          else if(res is _QueryResult)
          {
              if(res.rows.length==0) compl.complete(-1);
              else                   compl.complete(res.rows[0]["rowsAffected"]);
          }
          else throw "unknown response";
      })
      .catchError((err)
      {
          compl.completeError(err);  
      });
      return compl.future;
   }

   /// formats and write a command to the socket
   Future<dynamic> _SendCommand(String command)
   {
      // prepare buffer for response
      _receiveBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      
      _completer = new Completer();
      String cmd = command.length.toString() + "\r\n" + command;
      _socket.write(cmd);

      return _completer.future;
   }

   void _onDone()
   {
       //print("onDone()");
       //socket.destroy();
   }
   
   void _onError(error)
   {
       print("error occurred: $error");
   }
   
   /// receive data from socket and build a command string
   /// 
   /// client sends text-based commands with the format:
   /// size_of_command_string + "\r\n" + command_string
   void _receiveData(data)
   {      
      _receiveBuffer.write(data);
            
      String content = _receiveBuffer.toString();
      
      if(content.indexOf("\r\n")>0)
      {
         int x = content.indexOf("\r\n");
         int len = int.parse(content.substring(0,x)); // size of command string
         
         String cmd = content.substring(x+2);
         if(cmd.length==len)
         {           
           _completer.complete(cmd);           
         }              
      }
   }
   
   /// translates generic json result into a Result type
   dynamic _parseResult(String JSON)
   {
      Map result = json.decode(JSON);
      
           if(result["type"]=="ok")       return new _OkResult("ok");      
      else if(result["type"]=="error")    return new _ErrorResult(result["error"]);      
      else if(result["type"]=="query")    return new _QueryResult(result["rows"], result["columns"]);            
      else if(result["type"]=="table")    return new _TableResult(result["tablename"], result["rows"], result["columns"]);
      else if(result["type"]=="postback") return new _PostBackResult(result["idcolumn"], result["identities"]);
      else throw "unknown response";
   }         
}

class _ErrorResult
{
   String error;
   
   _ErrorResult(String error)
   {
      this.error = error;
   }
}

class _OkResult
{
   String ok;
   
   _OkResult(String ok)
   {
      this.ok = ok;
   }
}

class _QueryResult
{
   List rows;
   Map  columns;

   _QueryResult(List rows, Map columns)
   {
      this.rows = rows;
      this.columns = columns;
      
      // fix types 
      for(var fieldName in columns.keys)
      {
         TypeFixer.fixColumn(rows, fieldName, columns[fieldName]);
      }
   }  
}

class _TableResult
{
   String tableName;
   List rows;   
   List columns;
   
   _TableResult(String tableName, List rows, List columns)
   {
       this.tableName = tableName;
       this.rows = rows;
       this.columns = columns;       
   }
}

class _PostBackResult
{
   String idcolumn;
   List<int> identities;
   
   _PostBackResult(String idcolumn, List<int> identities)
   {
       this.idcolumn = idcolumn;
       this.identities = identities;
   }
}

/// translates a JSON encoded SQL type into a Dart type
class TypeFixer
{
   /// fix string data type coming from JSON into proper Dart data type
   static void fixColumn(List<dynamic> rows, String columnName, String columnType)
   {
       if(columnType=="datetime")
       {
         for(int t=0;t<rows.length;t++) 
         {
            if(rows[t][columnName]!=null) rows[t][columnName] = DateTime.parse(rows[t][columnName]);
         }   
       }
   }  
}
```